# How to get notify-send working on Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I'd like to be able to cause notification to appear on a Pi Desktop.

I've been running a recent Raspbian Jessie on a Pi 3, fully updated. I have `libnotify-bin` and `notification-daemon` installed (and rebooted thereafter). I am logged in as `pi`, and `ps` shows `notification-daemon` running.

However

```
$ notify-send Testing
```

has no visible effect. A quick search hasn't turned up a relevant logfile to examine, and Googling turns up stale info. What am I missing? What are my next steps?

**Update:** Steve's suggestion below solved the problem. While poking at it, I also was reminded that setting `DISPLAY=:0` is necessary to cause notifications to appear from an ssh session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to manually start the notification daemon:

```
/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

you will get an error and the daemon will not start. The error message is something like this:

> Error retrieving accessibility bus address:
>   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was
>   not provided by any .service files

To fix this install the at-spi2-core package:

```
sudo apt install at-spi2-core
```

confirm the fix by invoking the daemon:

```
/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

and then from a separate terminal window send a test message:

notify-send "Test" "It works!"

Answer (score 3):

This is for posterity:

I did some more digging. The descriptions all said, "... to a notification daemon".

So I did a search like: `apt-cache search notification daemon`

And got some other packages.

I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install mate-notification-daemon mate-notification-daemon-common
```

and the notify-send now works.