# Raspbian Sretch: notify-send does not display message on desktop

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have installed `libnotify-bin`, and `notify-osd`

All looks good. Yet when I do

> $notify-send 'hello'

I see nothing

Is there a service that I should turn on or something?

Jerry

Answer (score 2):

For Posterity:

All the descriptions I saw stated that it sent notifications "to a notification daemon"

So I did a apt-cache search of notification daemon, and got a few.

I installed:

sudo apt-get install mate-notification-daemon mate-notification-daemon-common

and did the notify-send, and it now works fine.

Comment: Hello Jerry - Please `accept` your answer by clicking on the "check mark". Otherwise, this Q will be floating around in the system, and recycled continuously.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a `notify-send` user, but you might try the following:

1. read the `man page` for `send-notify`; i.e. from the command prompt:

> man notify-send

2. if that fails, read [this related Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75299/how-to-get-notify-send-working-on-raspbian-jessie) which gives some specific advice.

Let us know if that doesn't work.

Also, you can find useful answers on your own using 'Google'. For example, try Googling `notify-send raspberry pi`. If you do this, you'll find the linked Q&A above in the 2nd position, and other potentially useful information. In other words, "read first, question later"